# onUserInteraction not called

Tags: android

I want to implement user inactivity event. I have so many screens and each has many edittexts. So I implemented `onUserInteraction()`method to detect user action on the screen. But unfortunately when user is typing while cursor is inside edittext. `onUserInteraction()` never gets called. One possible solutions is to implement text change listener but I have to implement it in all the edittexts that I don't want to do.

So is there any other solution so that I can get key press even inside activity itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a common textwatcher for all the edit text in an activity.

**Declaration:**

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String text = editable.toString();
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.name:
                model.setName(text);
                break;
            case R.id.email:
                model.setEmail(text);
                break;
            case R.id.phone:
                model.setPhone(text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setText(model.getName());
name.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(name));

email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
email.setText(model.getEmail());
email.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(email));

phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
phone.setText(model.getPhone());
phone.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(phone));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am finding general solution as there are quit lot edittex.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have base activity for all activities. if this is the case. you just need to implement TextWatcher in base activity. And in every EditText use setAddTextChangeListener(this). Whenever text is changed in any EdiText of Any Activity you will get call back to base activity. I hope that helps you